# Kotlin Operators ?, ?., ?: open source implementation

Tags: kotlin

I am pretty new to Kotlin, I am looking at the null safety and Elvis operators and would like to know more on how these are implemented to work on top of JVM.

Operators I am interested to know the implementation of:

`?` `?.` `?:`

But I am unable to locate any source associated with these. Are the implementations hidden? From my IDE also I cannot locate any source related to these, magic?

[image]

From the [Kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html): It specifies that Kotlin is an open source language: *Kotlin is an open-source statically typed programming language that targets the JVM, Android, JavaScript and Native*

**Note:**  I know I don't need to specify null on the right hand side of the Elvis, this is just to send my point across in the screen grab.

Comment: It might be that these are syntactic sugar rewritten by the compiler into underlying operators or method calls.

Comment: I am not sure on how to trace them to their original implementation, just wondering if some enlightened soul could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm no expert on the Kotlin compiler. I just looked at the source code.

The tokens are defined [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/29b23e79f32791e456a5b4a453277f0f0b3e984d/compiler/psi/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/lexer/KtTokens.java#L116-L118):

```java
KtSingleValueToken SAFE_ACCESS = new KtSingleValueToken("SAFE_ACCESS", "?.");
KtSingleValueToken ELVIS       = new KtSingleValueToken("ELVIS", "?:");
KtSingleValueToken QUEST       = new KtSingleValueToken("QUEST", "?");
```

These tokens are parsed by the Kotlin compiler itself, they are not defined in Java. This is why you cannot jump to a definition - they are re-written by the compiler.

I don't know how they are implemented, but checking out the Kotlin source and using the above tokens as a starting point might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Those features are "embedded" into the language. So you can't really dig into the code **at compile time**. An equivalent example to this would be trying to get the implementation of a `while` loop or a `when` statement. Those are language features that just generate compiled code

One thing that you could do if you're curious would be to decompile a simple program using them and check the result. However, as the generated bytecode may include some optimizations, the result might differ between different use cases.

The most important thing you need to know is **what they do** and **how to use them**. You can find an example of equivalent behaviour between null safe operators and java code in the [Kotlin Koans](https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans/Introduction/Nullable%20types/Task.kt), in which this Java code

```
public void sendMessageToClient(
    @Nullable Client client,
    @Nullable String message,
    @NotNull Mailer mailer
) {
    if (client == null || message == null) return;

    PersonalInfo personalInfo = client.getPersonalInfo();
    if (personalInfo == null) return;

    String email = personalInfo.getEmail();
    if (email == null) return;

    mailer.sendMessage(email, message);
}
```

can be rewritten in Kotlin as

```
val email = client?.personalInfo?.email
if (email != null && message != null) {
    mailer.sendMessage(email, message)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to set null on the right side of the elvis operator, the elvis operator is for handling non nullable case.

```
val info:EuiccInfo? = msg?.euiccInfo
```

`val info` - defined as nullable so it can be set null as well, if msg is null (`msg?` means msg can be null too, and if msg is null it will not access to `.euiccInfo`) info will be null.

lets assume info defined as non nullable val

```
val info:EuiccInfo = msg?.euiccInfo
```

compiler will not allow you to set info null value because msg is nullable,
so you have to handle non null case.

```
val info: EuiccInfo = msg?.euiccInfo ?: someDefaultNonNullValue (EuiccInfo())
```

it's unnecessary (and nonsense) to handle null case with Elvis operator because it will be set null if msg is null or `msg?.euiccInfo` is null.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question at the bottom as a note, why I have taken `?: null` as an `example`

Comment: ok, Thanks, maybe I didn't noticed or you updated the question after my answer maybe.